# iOS 10.2 playback issue

Tags: ios, playback

I have built a `music-playing app`. I added such code in my appdelegate and I have checked the box of **Audio**, **AirPlay**, and **Picture** in Picture in my project.

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

It works well in my iOS 8 and iOS 10 device in the background, but it doesn't work in iOS 10.2. I run my app in iOS 10.2, and play some audio from network, it won't play next after the last one has finished when I enter into the background or lock the screen.

After I go to foreground again, app received `AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification` twice, and I log the user info of the notification which showed as first time `AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey = 1;`  and second time `AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionKey = 0;AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey = 0;`.

**It‘s so odd that I doubt whether the iOS 10.2 bug about AVFoundation. How to fix it?** Thanks very much.